# Tiered pricing not displaying

Tags: magento

I am trying to set up tiered pricing for particular customer groups.

I have set up the group, assigned a customer to it and created a tier price in the product.

When I login using the account I created, I do not see the tier price.

Is there any setting in the attribute `Tier Price` that I need to configure?

Thanks

Comment: Have you refreshed your indexes? Are you sure the new customer is in appropriate group?

Comment: I have refreshed the indexes and the customer is in the correct group. I have created a store `Default Config -> Manage Stores -> My Store -> English`. This value is 1. In the database, the tier pricing has a `website_id` of 1. `var_dump($this->getTierPriceHtml())` returns null in the prodict view template as well

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Check that your tier price is lower than regular price.

Comment: Thank you!  This was exactly my issue!

Answer (score 2):

This solved also the problem for Group Price. If you insert group price higher then standard price, Magento show always standard price.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you are facing the issue - be aware that the tier price added to product in backend has to be entered as pr. unit price - and not the total price of the quantity of which you are adding the tier-price.

So if original price is 500$
And the tier price for 2 is 400.

You need to insert:
Quantity: 2 | Price: 200

And NOT Quantity: 2 | Price: 400.